# Añadir elementos en un multiconjunto de la clase Pair pero si se añaden dos veces el mismo, añada uno y ponga a la derecha un 2

Tags: java

estoy trabajando con multiconjuntos en java.
Tengo el constructor y los siguientes métodos add.
Pero no pasa la siguiente prueba:
set_0.add("eo,1)
set_0.add("eo")

The new value is [Pair("eo",1),Pair("eo",1)]
but it should contain the items [Pair("eo,2)]
¿Cómo prodría arreglarlo?

```
public MultiSetList() {
    this.elementos = new NodePositionList<Pair<Element,Integer>>();
    }


public void add(Element elem) {
        Pair<Element,Integer> newPair = new Pair<Element,Integer>(elem,1);
        elementos.addLast(newPair);
        }
public void add(Element elem, int n) {
        Pair<Element,Integer> newPair = new Pair<Element,Integer>(elem,n);
        if (n<0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }   
        if(n!=0) {
            elementos.addLast(newPair);
        }
    }
```

He modificado el método como me dijiste, mi única duda es que poner en el incremento.

```
public void add(Element elem, int n) {
        Pair<Element,Integer> newPair = new Pair<Element,Integer>(elem,n);
        if (n<0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }   
        if (elements == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        Position<Pair<Element,Integer>> cursor= elements.first();
        boolean corte= false;

        while(cursor != null && !corte){
            if(eqNull(cursor.element().getLeft(),elem)) { //método auxiliar 
//que compare los elementos nulos, pues elem podría ser null
                corte=true;
                elements.set(cursor,incremento); //Mi duda está aquí, que 
//que pongo en el incremento, pues tiene que ser de tipo Position<Pair<Element,Integer>>

            }
            else {
                if(cursor==elements.last()) {  
                    elements.addLast(newPair);
            cursor=null;
                }
                else {
             cursor= elements.next(cursor);

            }
        }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Podrían ayudarme por favor?

Comment: Faltaría saber que pasa cuando agregas un elemento repetido. Que política tiene el método add.?

Comment: Cuando agregas un elemento repetido, debería aparecer la parte Integer incrementada, es decir, si ya tienes [Pair(“eo”,1),Pair(“vale”,1)] y haces un set_0.add(“eo”) debería aparecer [Pair(“eo”,2),Pair(“vale”,1)] y no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

> Ahi tendrias que hacer un método buscar element, y si esta, incrementar en uno a el Integer de lo contrario lo agregas al final, en tu codigo solo lo agregas al final de la lista. 
>   Tenes que recorrer la lista para buscar si esta el Pair que contiene el elemento que buscas, como no hay elementos repetetidos porque si lo hubuiera le sumarias 1 al Integer entonces tenes que hacer un recorrido NO exhaustivo, osea recorremos y si lo encontramos cortamos el recorrido. Podriamos hacer un iterator de positions, pero para los efectos practicos vamos a recorrerlo a mano.
>   La estrategia va a ser guardar la primer posicion de la lista en una variable llamada cursor, a la que le vamos a preguntar si tiene contenida el elemento que buscamos y si no lo tiene que vaya a la siguiente posicion, y asi hasta que lo encuentra o hasta que se termina la lista;

```
//tenes q agregar los try y catch y cuando uses first() pregunta siempre y
// la lista no esta vacia.
Position<Pair<Element,Integer>> cursor= lista.first();
//variable de corte
boolean corte= false;

while(cursor!=null&&!corte){
  //aca un if, que compare element que esta dentro del cursor, dentro de
  //Pair, con el element que estas buscando. si es, entonces usas
  //lista.set(cursor,incremento) y corte =true; de lo contrario

  if(cursor==lista.last())
    //significa que el elemento no estaba, aca podrias agregar al final de
    //la lista el nuevo par.  
    cursor=null;
  else
     cursor= lista.next(cursor);

}
```

> Así es como podes recorrer una lista, intenta hacerlo y pregunta que dudas especificas que tengas de tu código.
>   Si llegaste hasta incrementar entonces ya tenes la posicion; en la  posicion tenes el pair y en el pair tenes integer;

```
//a getV() creo que le llamas getRight()
Integer incremento = cursor.element().getV();
incremento++;
Pair<Element,Integer> nuevo = new Pair(corsor.element().getK(),incremento);
lista.set(cursor,nuevo);
```

Comment: Me podrías decir cómo hacerlo?

Comment: He editado nuevamente el método, mi duda está en el incremento

Comment: fijate la modificacion que hice o no se si te avisa la pagina que modifico la respuesta

Comment: Intenté eso pero me salta el siguiente error:                                                     The method set(Position<Pair<Element,Integer>>, Pair<Element,Integer>) in the type PositionList<Pair<Element,Integer>> is not applicable for the 
 arguments (Position<Pair<Element,Integer>>, int)

Comment: Esta bien, porque el  E de Set es un Pair no un Integer, ahi lo modifique